# Por que me marca list index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

puede alguien decirme que error tengo en mi codigo si no es mucha molestia.

```
def CreaLista(k):
    L = []
    for i in range(k+1):
        L.append(0)
    return L

def CountingSort(A,k):
    C=CreaLista(k)
    B=CreaLista(len(A)-1)
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]+1
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1]
    for j in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
        B[C[A[j]]]=A[j]
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]-1
    return B

lista = [0,9,7,81,4,5,68,3,541]
k = len(lista[1:])
CountingSort(lista, k)
```

Este es el error que me da:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6ba25f80b3f> in <module>()
     19 lista = [0,9,7,81,4,5,68,3,541]
     20 k = len(lista[1:])
---> 21 CountingSort(lista, k)

<ipython-input-1-d6ba25f80b3f> in CountingSort(A, k)
      9     B=CreaLista(len(A)-1)
     10     for j in range(1, len(A)):
---> 11         C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]+1
     12     for i in range(1, k+1):
     13         C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hola Johan, bienvenido. En que linea te da el fallo? Has hecho algun tipo de debug o log?

Comment: En mi caso este error me da cuando la lista de elementos a barrer en una secuencia "for" es muy grande. Cuando tengo pocos elementos en la lista me corre el programa sin problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpreto que tienes un error de implementación del algoritmo *CountingSort*. El parámetro `k` no debería ser el número de elementos de la lista a ordenar, sinó el valor máximo de la lista. En el ejemplo que muestras, el valor máximo de la lista a ordenar es `541`. Por lo tanto, deberías cambiar la llamada a la función para que `k` tome el valor deseado:

```
lista = [0,9,7,81,4,5,68,3,541]
k = max(lista[1:])  # max() en vez de len()
CountingSort(lista, k)
```

Comment: Esto me funciono bastante bien. Estoy muy agradecido por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 5):

En Python, las listas empiezan por 0. En tu caso, en la primera iteración del primer for, `A[j]` vale 9. C sólo tiene 9 elementos, por lo que sólo podrías acceder hasta `C[8]`. En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que utilices la función [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) en vez de utilizar range. Los bucles for te quedarían mucho más limpios:

```
for key, value in enumerate(A):
    pass
```